# Amazon Redshift - Get week wise sales count by category

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have daily sales data as below. I am trying to group by sales week wise.

I tried using group by that gives total count for the period, how could I modify the query to obtain an output as shown below:

**Expected output:**

```
Last N days,Count,Category

Last 7 days,225,Category_1
Last 14 days,136,Category_2
Last 7 days,172,Category_1
Last 14 days,321,Category_2
```

**Input data:**

```
Date,*Sales*,Category

01-06-2018,10,Category_1
01-06-2018,19,Category_1
03-06-2018,3,Category_1
04-06-2018,13,Category_1
05-06-2018,10,Category_1
06-06-2018,14,Category_1
07-06-2018,20,Category_1
08-06-2018,49,Category_1
09-06-2018,5,Category_1
10-06-2018,4,Category_1 
11-06-2018,20,Category_1
12-06-2018,49,Category_1
13-06-2018,5,Category_1
14-06-2018,4,Category_1
01-06-2018,10,Category_1
01-06-2018,34,Category_2
03-06-2018,22,Category_2
04-06-2018,13,Category_2
05-06-2018,1,Category_2
06-06-2018,9,Category_2
07-06-2018,60,Category_2
08-06-2018,9,Category_2
09-06-2018,35,Category_2
10-06-2018,41,Category_2 
11-06-2018,2,Category_2
12-06-2018,9,Category_2
13-06-2018,35,Category_2
14-06-2018,41,Category_2
```

Query tried:

```
select count(*),Category from sales
group by Category;
```

I am using Amazon redshift DB.

Could anyone help,thanks..

**Update as of 06/19:**

```
select Category,
sum(case when date >= dateadd(day, -7, CURRENT_DATE) then count(sales) else 0 end) as count_07,
sum(case when date >= dateadd(day, -14, CURRENT_DATE) then count(sales) else 0 end) as count_14
from sales
group by Category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the values in separate columns.  Something like this:

```
select category, 
       sum(case when date >= dateadd(day, -7, CURRENT_DATE) then sales else 0 end) as count_07,
       sum(case when date >= dateadd(day, -14, CURRENT_DATE) then sales else 0 end) as count_14
from sales s
group by category;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am getting an error "aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function" when I try the above approach. Could you please advice.

Comment: @darkhorse . . . There are no nested functions, so I don't know where such an error would be coming from.

Comment: I have added the updated query in the initial post (Titled as "update as of 06/19"). I have edited the column name to 'Sales' and I am trying to find the count of records. Running this query throws an error "aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function". Could you please assist. Tnx..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are one [DATEADD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) away from the solution.

For seven days, it should be as follows:

```
Select Count(*),Category From sales Where Date >= Dateadd(day,-7, CURRENT_DATE)
```

Group By Category;

Change `-7` to `-14` to get last 14 days.