# Redshift - Aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, amazon-redshift

I am trying to build a SQL query that would count the sum of sales made based on certain values as shown below:

Given below is how my dataset is:

```
cust_name,sales_count,day_count
cust_a,100,3
cust_a,200,5
cust_a,150,7
cust_a,120,1
cust_a,180,10
cust_a,100,8
cust_b,20,3
cust_b,10,4
cust_b,50,6
cust_b,60,8
cust_b,15,9
```

I would like to get the output in the below format

```
cust_name,sales_count,day_count
cust_a,280,last_14
cust_a,450,last_7
cust_b,85,last_14
cust_b,80,last_7
```

Given below is the case statement I tried to build

```
select cust_name, 
       sum(case when day_count > 7 then count(sales_count) else 0 end) as count_14,
       sum(case when day_count < 7 then count(sales_count) else 0 end) as count_7
from sales
group by cust_name;
```

I am using a Amazon Redshift Database.

Found a similar issue in this link ([Amazon Redshift - Get week wise sales count by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853023/amazon-redshift-get-week-wise-sales-count-by-category/50856452?noredirect=1#comment88838565_50856452)) but I keep getting **aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function**.

Could anyone help trouble shoot this. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `pendo_visitor_id`  column  from your sample data?

Comment: Sorry I meant it to be "sales_count". Typo from my side. I have edited the original message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question, you can try this query.

use `SUM` and `CASE WHEN` Expression.

```
select cust_name, 
       sum(case when day_count > 7 then sales_count else 0 end) as count_14,
       sum(case when day_count < 7  then sales_count else 0 end) as count_7
from sales
group by cust_name;
```

**EDIT:**

Becasue `Aggregate functions` can't nest multiple times.

If you want to fix

```
sum(case when day_count > 7 then count(sales_count) else 0 end)
```

You can try to write a subquery to fix it.

```
SELECT cust_name,
       sum(case when day_count > 7 then cnt else 0 end) as count_14,
       sum(case when day_count < 7 then cnt else 0 end) as count_7
FROM (
    SELECT cust_name,(case when day_count > 7 then 1
                           when day_count < 7 then 2
                           else null
                      end) grp,
          count(sales_count) cnt
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY cust_name,
             (case when day_count > 7 then 1
                   when day_count < 7 then 2
                   else null
             end)
)t 
WHERE grp is not null
GROUP BY cust_name
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Since I am trying to get the count(sales_count), I get an error "Aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function" when I change the case statement with count(sales_count). Could you please assist.

Comment: Aggregate functions can't nest multiple times,  so you can try to write a subquery to fix it. you can see my edit answer:)  @KevinNash

Answer (score 2):

to produce the desired output, what you need is just

`sum(case when day_count > 7 then sales_count else 0 end)`

what you have in the brackets is the expression which output you redirect to the sum function that aggregates it, so for `cust_a` it produces the following set of values:

```
cust_a,100,3 -> 0 (3<=7)
cust_a,200,5 -> 0 (5<=7)
cust_a,150,7 -> 0 (7<=7)
cust_a,120,1 -> 0 (1<=7)
cust_a,180,10 -> 180 (10>7)
cust_a,100,8 -> 100 (8>7)
```

and then the sum is 280